# How to combine GEOMs or linestrings from different rows

Tags: postgis, arcmap, postgresql

I am working with a set of data that includes common IDs and overlapping linestrings/geoms. I would like to combine the overlapping lines based on their common IDs, preferably in postgres. I can run the combo process on either format. The linestrings are lat/long.

The data as linestring (lat/long) looks like this (with each # being a lat/long pair):

```
ID     geometry-points
11     1 3 56
11     12 45 7
11      234 6 8
12       3 5
12     1 
12           78
```

And would return like this

```
11     12345678
12     13578
```

Comment: Great question. Would love to hear an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You want to union and dissolve those lines based on `ID`; this is trivial with `ST_Union` working on groups:

```
SELECT id,
       ST_Union(geom) AS geom
FROM   <your_table>
GROUP BY
        id
;
```